# Windows xp laptop wifi internet to ethernet port for TV

Tags: windows, windows-xp, wireless-networking, ethernet, tv

I have a Dell Laptop running Windows XP Media Centre edition with Internet using Wifi in my bedroom on 1st floor. The Wifi router if on the Ground floor. I recently purchased a Sony Bravia TV with a ethernet port. 
Now i want to tether the internet connection from Wifi on my laptop out through the Ethernet port to the TV.

Kindly suggest what H/W do i need, S/W configuration etc, to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

- D

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to have internet on your TV, I'd skip the wireless part and use two powerline adapters to connect the tv to the router.

Comment: Great idea. I've used the D-Link stuff and it works well, and is much quicker than wi-fi. +1 for you.